# Converting ArrayList<Object> into Json using Gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

To start off, i'm reasonable new to programming in general. For school i'm working on an android project in which i would like to be able to save data using SharedPreferences, using Gson to turn an ArrayList into Json. However, whenever I try to run it (emulator) I get the following messages in logcat:

```
Do full code cache collection, code=125KB, data=66KB
After code cache collection, code=104KB, data=41KB
Background concurrent copying GC freed 36221(1156KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(60KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 1708KB/3MB, paused 5.863ms total 115.252ms
Do partial code cache collection, code=123KB, data=56KB
After code cache collection, code=123KB, data=56KB
Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
```

This will go on for a while untill my app crashes. I do not run into this problem when saving other data the same way I'm trying to do here.

Code:

adding objects to array

```
for(int x = 0; x < board.getWidth(); x++ ) {
                for( int y = 0; y < board.getHeight(); y++ ) {

                    Field field = (Field) MainActivity.game.getGameBoard().getObject(x, y);
                    fieldArray.add(field);
                }
            }
```

converting and saving

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
Gson objectGson = new Gson();
String objectJson = objectGson.toJson(fieldArray);
edits.putString("gameobjects", objectJson);
editor.apply();
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Do you have cyclic references in your `Field`s? Maybe some neighbours defined through `left, right, up, down` references?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<YourObject>>(){}.getType();

listGalerias = new Gson().fromJson(json, listType);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I indeed use Typetokens for retrieving the data back from memory and converting back to the right objects, however the problem occurs while turning the Gson in the Json object in the first place. So specifically at this line:

    String objectJson = objectGson.toJson(fieldArray);

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I tried here something like this, I have an object Post with some fields, I used Gson to populate this object

```
val url = "http://www.projectconnect.com.br/make/api/post/list/list.php"

val json = URL(url).readText()

val gson = Gson()

val retorno = gson.fromJson(json, Retorno::class.java)

val posts : List<Post> = retorno.list
```

the result was this
[Post object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlEJ7.png)

later I made this

```
val arrayPosts = arrayOfNulls<Post>(posts.size)
arrayPosts.set(0, posts[0])

for (i in 0 until posts.size) {
    arrayPosts[i] = posts[i]
}

val objectJson = gson.toJson(arrayPosts)
```

and the result was this
[my objectJson populated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYNXy.png)

here is the
[objectJson value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxT8h.png)